# How to use a constant in SOQL in a test class

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, failing-tests, test-setup

I have the following test class:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=false)
private with sharing class classNameTest {

     @isTest
     static testMethod void methodName(){

        // declare a constant
        private static final String PROFILE_NAME = 'System Administrator';

        try{
            // use a constant in SOQL
            Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name=PROFILE_NAME limit 1];
        }

         // remaining code

}
```

when I try to save the file, it gives me an error:

> unexpected token 'PROFILE_NAME'.

How can I use the constant in an SOQL query?

Answer (score 5):

It is a bind variable, so it needs to be used with colon. Also it should be declared outside the test method. Moreover, when you use `@IsTest` annotation on the method, you do not need to add `testMethod` modifier (which is deprecated). Finally, `SeeAllData` is false by default for test class, so it is not necessary to add this annotation to the class:

```
@IsTest
private with sharing class classNameTest {
    // declare constant
    private static final String PROFILE_NAME = 'System Administrator';

    @IsTest
    static void methodName(){        
        try {
            // use constant in soql
            Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = :PROFILE_NAME limit 1];
        } catch (Exception e){}
         
        // remaining code
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer that goes into some "why" not just "what" or "how" - I love those answers. :) 1) You might want to make your sentence read as, *"Moreover, when you use `@IsTest` annotation on a method, you do not need..."* (I added "on a method".) Just to clarify any possible ambiguity, since `@IsTest` is also used on the class. 2) You might also want to point out that `testmethod` is deprecated and `@IsTest` is preferred/suggested.

Comment: @Moonpie Thank you for your comment, I have updated the answer, also, feel free to edit it, if you want)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a colon in the SOQL query. It should be

`Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name=:PROFILE_NAME limit 1];`

The colon is mandatory as it will let Salesforce know that you are trying to **bind** an Apex code variable in the SOQL query.
For more details, please refer the official Salesforce documentation on this link
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm

Also, the constant should be declared outside the method at the class level.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Thank you for contributing.

Comment: What is the difference? ***Why*** should there be a colon in that location? Can you elaborate? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/357513/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written right now).